# How to define partials for unscaled models (with ResponseSurface components)?

Tags: python, optimization, openmdao

I'm trying to run the optimization of a large model that contains `MetaModelUnstructuredComps` (MMUCs) where outputs are estimated using `ReponseSurfaces`. I have already created this model manually first and that works as expected. However, in that model all variables were scaled (also the inputs and outputs of the response surfaces and other components). The partials for the MMUCs are done using finite difference with default settings. In a second implementation (which is automatically built using the OpenLEGO package) the inputs and outputs of the components (surrogate models, contraints, etc.) are not scaled (though the design variables are scaled for the driver using the `ref` and `ref0` arguments and constraints+objective are also scaled within their equation). When I try to optimize this model (`pyOptSparse/SLSQP`), the optimization does not succeed and has a hard time to meet several equality constraints. Interestingly, when I use `approx_totals(step_calc='rel')` on the model, then the optimization does work. This gave me the impression that something is wrong with the partials that are calculated and combined.

So I tried to debug this issue by using `compute_totals()` to see what the total derivatives are at the start of the optimization. Here are some typical values for two responses `FR` and `Gc.WE`:

```
    of / wrt      | approx_totals  | partials   |
    ---------------------------------------------
    FR / w_WE       -2824914,296     3166,669425
    FR / w_ESF      -7039070,86     -3447,735199
    FR / D          -1416,834424     1,718097909
    FR / w_L        -1594560,102     11755399102
    FR / ESF        -10741467,19    -71835372264
    FR / w_D        -305835126,1     190116092,9
    FR / h          -132,8664739    -1053392,711
    FR / Theta      -7663550,5       76607039579
    FR / w_Theta    -2458516,552     42170,96747
    FR / M          -5692867,582    -1,02E+11
    FR / Lambda     -114534,707      2831614491
    FR / L          -176,6461801     728,0673131
    FR / WE         -833,5583125     3240,452002
    FR / tc         -132833949,9    -17828405236
    FR / w_WT       -2606083,221     99243,27639
    FR / WT         -176,646275      1663865,719
    FR / AR         -3220216,113    -3,03E+11
    FR / Sref       -5339,233451     340740598,7
    Gc.WE / w_WE    -354442,2873    -10,94512505
    Gc.WE / w_ESF   -883192,9447    -7,231199285
    Gc.WE / D       -177,7706417     0,2982562
    Gc.WE / w_L     -200069,6665     0
    Gc.WE / ESF     -1347733,361     0
    Gc.WE / w_D     -38373164,66     0
    Gc.WE / h       -16,6709147     -0,689845824
    Gc.WE / Theta   -961539,6393     0
    Gc.WE / w_Theta -308470,3246     0
    Gc.WE / M       -714285,1914     13180,76857
    Gc.WE / Lambda  -14370,66473     0
    Gc.WE / L       -22,16381204     0
    Gc.WE / WE      -104,5865158     1
    Gc.WE / tc      -16666686,96     0
    Gc.WE / w_WT    -326985,5298     0
    Gc.WE / WT      -22,16381204     0
    Gc.WE / AR      -404040,8959     0
    Gc.WE / Sref    -669,9145362     0
---------------------------------------------
```

To my surprise, the totals with `approx_totals()` are not always what they are expected to be (0 is expected for `Gc.WE / D` for example), but the optimization does work using the `approx_totals()`. In addition, at the end of the optimization these totals are equal or close to zero so it seems to be handling that correctly. The totals that are determine based on partials are more in line with my expectations (at least the 0's and 1's), but the optimization does not run correctly.

Unfortunately I cannot share the full code here. I'm working on a small working example that would show the same issue, but haven't found it so far. Just wanted to put my question already out here to see if there's any advice on this.

I expected that the model would work the same with or without the `approx_totals()`, since all components in the model will determine the partials with finite difference or the partials are provided analytically (of which I'm sure they are correct after checking with `check_partials()`). Since the inputs of the different components are not scaled, I have tried to adjust the `step_size` of the `fd` method to match the range of the input (so for `Gc.WE / D`, instead of `step_size=1E-6` this was changed to `step_size=10000*1E-6` since `D` is between 0 and 20000), but to no avail.

Do you have any advice on how to further debug this issue? How can partials best be declared for components where the inputs have vastly different ranges? Or could there be another issue if optimization with `approx_totals()` works, but not without it, other than something being wrong with the partials?

**Small working example based on first answer**

```
    import numpy as np

    from openmdao.api import Problem, Group, ResponseSurface, IndepVarComp, MetaModelUnStructuredComp

    x_train = np.arange(0., 10.)
    y_train = np.arange(10., 20.)
    z_train = x_train**2 + y_train**2

    p = Problem()
    p.model = m = Group()

    params = IndepVarComp()
    params.add_output('x', val=0.)
    params.add_output('y', val=0.)

    m.add_subsystem('params', params, promotes=['*'])

    sm = MetaModelUnStructuredComp(default_surrogate=ResponseSurface())
    sm.add_input('x', val=0.)
    sm.add_input('y', val=0.)
    sm.add_output('z', val=0.)

    sm.options['train:x'] = x_train
    sm.options['train:y'] = y_train
    sm.options['train:z'] = z_train

    # With or without the line below does not matter
    # Only when method is set to fd, then RuntimeWarning disappears
    sm.declare_partials('*', '*', method='exact')

    m.add_subsystem('sm', sm, promotes=['*'])

    m.add_design_var('x', lower=0., upper=10.)
    m.add_design_var('y', lower=0., upper=10.)
    m.add_objective('z')

    p.setup()

    p['x'] = 5.
    p['y'] = 12.

    p.run_model()

    print('\nSM-value z: {}'.format(float(p['z'])))
    print('theoretical z: {}'.format(float(p['x']**2 + p['y']**2)))

    totals = p.compute_totals()

    print('\nSM-value z wrt x: {}'.format(totals[('sm.z', 'params.x')][0][0]))
    print('theoretical value z wrt x: {}'.format(2*p['x'][0]))
    print('\nSM-value z wrt y: {}'.format(totals[('sm.z', 'params.y')][0][0]))
    print('theoretical value z wrt y: {}'.format(2*p['y'][0]))
```

Based on this example I get the following log:

```
/Users/imcovangent/Documents/PhD/Software/OpenMDAO/openmdao/components/meta_model_unstructured_comp.py:287: RuntimeWarning:Because the MetaModelUnStructuredComp 'sm' uses a surrogate which does not define a linearize method,
OpenMDAO will use finite differences to compute derivatives. Some of the derivatives will be computed
using default finite difference options because they were not explicitly declared.
The derivatives computed using the defaults are:
    sm.z, sm.x
    sm.z, sm.y

SM-value z: 169.213661944
theoretical z: 169.0

SM-value z wrt x: 10.0415292063
theoretical value z wrt x: 10.0

SM-value z wrt y: 23.9584707937
theoretical value z wrt y: 24.0
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py:1018: RuntimeWarning: internal gelsd driver lwork query error, required iwork dimension not returned. This is likely the result of LAPACK bug 0038, fixed in LAPACK 3.2.2 (released July 21, 2010). Falling back to 'gelss' driver.
  warnings.warn(mesg, RuntimeWarning)
```

The first RunTimeWarning message was the source of my confusion. To get rid of it, I declared the partials with `method=fd`, but looking at it again, it seems to just give the warning, but it is actually using the `linearize` method of the surrogate model. Hence, the warning is incorrect for the `ResponseSurface` surrogate models.

Comment: Hi Imco! Could you maybe share the N2 diagram of the model? `check_totals()` gives the same result, as `approx_totals()`?

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to put a group around your `MetaModelUnstructured`instance, and then set the approx_totals method on that group in particular. This will allow you to isolate that one particular component. If you can get it to work/not work based on that then its 100% confirmed that its the meta-model and not some other component with bad partials. Your own test using a hand-coded metamodel vs the OpenMDAO component would definitely seem to imply the problem is there... but just one more sanity check would be nice.

Some of the surrogate models do have analytic derivatives, but some do not and then FD is used. It sounds like you're using the [ResponseSurface](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/a5ae82545979e6e529473f2efd81aaad24a273c9/openmdao/surrogate_models/response_surface.py) surrogate, which does provide analytic derivatives. But perhaps there is a bug in that implementation. If there is a bug, and you're not seeing anything show up in check_partials when you look, then I suggest taking the final optimized result (or some point close to it) and setting that as the initial condition, then call a single `run_model()` before calling `check_partials()`. If the above suggested sanity check proves that the problem is with your MetaModel comp. FY You can specify the name of the meta-model component specifically

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your swift answer. Concerning the first part of your reply, I will look into this to further isolate the problem and come back to that. With respect to the second part I have already added a small working example in the post to indicate where the confusion came from here. It seems OpenMDAO wrongly gave me a RuntimeWarning that the ResponseSurface surrogate has to use `fd`, which is why I declared my partials to use `fd` as to not get this warning anymore. However, despite the warning it is actually still using the `linearize` method.